# Carregar conteúdo de uma div dentro de outra div

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou com o seguinte problema. Como faço para carregar um conteúdo de uma `div` para dentro de outra `div` vazia que está no mesmo arquivo HTML?

Exemplo:

```
<div class="conteudo">
   <label> Teste 1 </label>
   <label> Teste 1 </label>
</div>
<div class="receber conteudo">

</div>
```

Eu queria jogar todo esse conteúdo da primeira `div` para dentro da segunda `div` vazia através de uma função jQuery, já tentei o método `find` mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Se esta utilizando ajax? e for imagem carregamento tem um exemplo entre o site http://www.loading.io

Comment: @KingRider não precisa de Ajax, ele quer apenas que as duas `label` sejam copiadas para a segunda `div`. Certo Marlon?

Comment: Isso mesmo @KingRider , eu preciso carregar todo um conteúdo de um formulário ja existente dentro de uma div vazia..

Comment: A resposta do Allan responde à sua pergunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em seu exemplo, os dois `divs` continham a classe `.conteudo`.

A fim de evitar conflito de nomes das classes, alterei o nome da classe no div que recebe o conteúdo: de `receber conteudo` para `receber_conteudo`.

Veja abaixo o exemplo funcionando:

```js
//
// JAVASCRIPT
//

$('#btnMoverConteudo').click(function(){
  // copia o conteúdo em .receber_conteudo
  $('.receber_conteudo').append($('.conteudo').html()); 
  // limpa o valor de conteúdo
  $('.conteudo').html(''); 
});
```

```css
//
// CSS
//

.receber_conteudo{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:15px;
 }

.conteudo{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:15px;
 }
```

```html
//
// HTML
//

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
   <label> Teste 1 </label>
   <label> Teste 1 </label>
</div>
<div class="receber_conteudo">

</div>
<input type="button" id="btnMoverConteudo" value="Mover"/>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. Muito obrigado Allan Andrade, problema resolvido!